# Como percorrer os valores de um [object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

Preciso obter os valores de cada chave dentro de um `loop`. Os valores são em "Blocos":

```
[  
   {  
      "estado":"Ceará",
      "cidade":"Fortaleza",
      "nome_revendedor":"Zélia",
      "telefone":"85 9999999",
      "email":"teste@teste.com.br"
   },
   {  
      "estado":"São Paulo",
      "cidade":"Carjai",
      "nome_revendedor":"Zezé",
      "telefone":"85 9999999",
      "email":"teste@teste.com.br"
   }
]
```

O que já tenho é basicamente um mapa em SVG que possui links. Esse links possuem uma `class` chamada **.estado**. A ideia é que ao clicar no estado tragam as suas respectivas informações:

```
 $('.estado').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var estado = $(this).attr('xlink:href');
     $.ajax({
             url: 'servo.php',
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             data: { estado: estado }
         })
         .done(function(data) {    
             $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
                 $("#titulo").html("Revedendor: " + JSON.stringify(obj.revendedor));    
             }) 


         });
     return false;
 });
```

Eu consigo obter as informações através de uma requisição e para fins de teste criei dois `array` e converti para `json`, `mas o objetivo é criar um loop através de uma consulta SQL e alimentar a variável $return_arr[$date][]`:

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {

    if (isset($_POST["estado"]) && !empty($_POST["estado"])) { //Checks if action value exists
        $key_estado = $_POST["estado"];
        buscar($key_estado);
    }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax()
{
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function buscar($key_estado)
{

    $return_arr = array();
    $date       = 'revendedor';

    $arr        = array(
        "estado" => "Ceará",
        "cidade" => "Fortaleza",
        "nome_revendedor" => "Zélia",
        "telefone" => "85 999999",
        "email" => "teste@teste.com.br"
    );

    $gg = array(
        "estado" => "São Paulo",
        "cidade" => "Carjai",
        "nome_revendedor" => "Zélia",
        "telefone" => "85 999999",
        "email" => "teste@teste.com.br"
    );

    $return_arr[$date][] = $gg;
    $return_arr[$date][] = $arr;

    echo json_encode(array(
        "revendedor" => $return_arr
    ));
}
?>
```

### Exemplo:

```
Estado: 
Cidade:
Revendedor:
Telefone: 
Email: 


Estado: 
Cidade:
Revendedor:
Telefone: 
Email: 

Estado: 
Cidade:
Revendedor:
Telefone: 
Email: 

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há maneiras diferentes de mostrar esses dados, mas criando uma tabela pode ser feito assim:

#### jsFiddle:

```js
var json = JSON.parse('[ { "estado":"Ceará", "cidade":"Fortaleza", "nome_revendedor":"Zélia", "telefone":"85 9999999", "email":"teste@teste.com.br" }, { "estado":"São Paulo", "cidade":"Carjai", "nome_revendedor":"Zezé", "telefone":"85 9999999", "email":"teste@teste.com.br"} ]');


var table = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(table);

var titulos = Object.keys(json[0]);
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
table.appendChild(tr);

titulos.forEach(function(titulo) {
    var th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerHTML = titulo;
    tr.appendChild(th);
});

json.forEach(function(obj) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) {
        table.appendChild(tr);
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = obj[prop];
        tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    table.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```css
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ccf;
    padding: 10px;
}
th {
    background-color: #aac;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q2brfps6/

Comment: Perfeito. Resolvido.